# Python: Why can't I define a 2d matrix from a parameter?

Tags: python, matrix, data-structures

Why can't I define a 2d n x n matrix in python by creating a variable and assigning it the value of a matrix parameter? I'm writing a function to transpose a matrix, but when I do this:

```
def transpose(m):
    new_matrix = m
    for i in range(len(m)):
        for k in range(len(m[0])):
            new_matrix[i][k] = m[k][i]
    return new_matrix


It returns this:
[1, 4, 7]
[4, 5, 8]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Note- The input is just:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
```

But it has the right output when I just directly create a matrix like this:

```
def transpose(m):
    new_matrix = [[0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0]]
    for i in range(len(m)):
        for k in range(len(m[0])):
            new_matrix[i][k] = m[k][i]
    return new_matrix

Output:
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]
[3, 6, 9]
```

I'm asking because I may get different n x n sized matrices and can't preset a blank matrix in python. Please correct any misunderstandings I may be having. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The original nested list isn't a new instance, you need to clone the list with `copy.deepcopy` like:

```
from copy import deepcopy
a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
def transpose(m):
    new_matrix = deepcopy(m)
    for i in range(len(m)):
        for k in range(len(m[0])):
            new_matrix[i][k] = m[k][i]
    return new_matrix
print(transpose(a))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I am not able to comment to Daniel Hao, but another option is:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
a_transpose = list(map(list, zip(*a)))
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: There is already working code, and I am not sure what kind of documentation is needed for this solution since it is pure python?